# Images Stored in mysql blob field not pulling back up PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing images in a MySql database Blob field.  When I try to pull them back out I get an image that doesn't work.  Any clue on if I'm storing it wrong or if its just the way I'm saving it?

```
if($_FILES['damage001']['tmp_name']){
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['damage001']['tmp_name']);
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

    $photo1_type = protect($_POST['photo1_type']);
    $photo1_desc = protect($_POST['photo1_desc']);


    $sql = "INSERT into `tbl_osd_attachments` SET 
    `osd_id`='$id',`picture`='$data',`type`='$photo1_type', description = '$photo1_desc';";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    //echo 'link to uploaded picture: <a href='.$url.'> Picture link! </a>';

    }else{ echo '<br><br>';}
```

Code for pulling the images:

```
$z2=mysql_result($result_pics,$z,"picture");

    echo "<img alt='embedded image' src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($z2)."' >";
```

I am in the process of switching from mysql to mysqli

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Shouldn't there be `header('Content-Length: '.strlen($z2));` and `header("Content-type: image/{$extension}");` before the `echo`?

Comment: Maybe `mysql_real_escape_string(...)` is modifying the content of `$data`, so retrieving it produces something else. Don't you then need to 'unescape' the string stored in your database? Better still, remove `mysql_real_escape_string(...)`.

Comment: You are correct.  I need to switch to MySQLi.  I am just goign to instead post the files to a folder.  I keep hearing about all the issues of storing them in database.